# using curl with php cannot connect peer reset

Tags: php, linux, curl

Trying to find why the connection is reset by peer. Any idea what to look for in wireshark or how to troubleshoot correctly to find a solution?

```
curl --tlsv1.0 https://www.xxx.com -v

Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  Trying ipaddress...
Connected to xxxx.com (ipaddress) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
TCP connection reset by peer
Closing connection 0
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
```

Comment: cat /etc/*-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.0 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.0"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.0 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.0:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.0
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.0
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-0-197 ec2-user]# uname -a                                                                             Linux ip-10-0-0-197.ec2.internal 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 11 13:37:49 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Changing AWS default MTU was the answer for me. Curl, etc. worked fine after that.

To make the setting permanent for eth0, edit the configuration file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and add the line MTU=1200 as shown below:

```
DEVICE=eth0
MTU=1500
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
```

Then, restart the interface (as root):
service network restart eth0

Resources:
https://serverfault.com/questions/594727/openssl-hangs-after-client-hello
http://www.redhat.com/magazine/002dec04/departments/tips_tricks/

Comment: If you're using Amazon Linux AMI, the file to edit is `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf` or `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Your resources helped me figure this out. Link to this change since it also requirins adding a different line to the file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/network_mtu.html#mtu-troubleshooting